# Clangd VSCodium can't find GTK-4 headers

Tags: c, gtk4, clangd, vscodium

I'm looking to learn how to use the GTK-4 library in C, so I've installed the official packages for my distribution (Manjaro), but I'm facing an issue...
Clangd can't find the gtk headers with `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` because in my `/usr/include/` directory, I have versions 2, 3, and 4 of gtk...
After doing some research, I found that during compilation, it's sufficient to use the parameters provided by `pkg-config --cflags gtk4` and `pkg-config --libs gtk4` for everything to proceed correctly...

Unfortunately, I haven't found out how to configure clangd so that the autocompletion in my IDE (VSCodium) works with these libraries... At the moment, since nothing seems to be defined for the editor, I get dozens of errors that render autocompletion completely unusable even though there are no errors during compilation...

I've tried using `compile_flags.txt` and `compile_commands.json`, I've tried configuring clangd with `.clangd`, but nothing has worked...

Does anyone have a solution?

(Sorry if my English is bad, I used an online translator from my native language...)

Comment: How did you create your `compile_commands.json`? It would also help answer the question if you attached [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs).